# How do you update a react whose questions are generated from an object?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, javascript-objects

I'm trying to create a form in react, where I have the questions pulled from a flask backend as a dictionary, where in React it results in an object. As a result, I have the following code when the component is getting rendered:

```
const [questions, setQuestions] = useState('');
const [answers, setAnswers] = useState('');

/// answers are pulled from api, with questions and answers set up to be equal. 
... 

{ Object.entries(questions).map(([key, question]) =>
 (
   <>
     <p> {question}</p>
     <textarea value = {answers[key]} onChange = {(e) => setAnswers(prevAnswer => ({...prevAnswer, key:e.target.value}))} 
     type = 'text' required />      
   </>
 )
)
}
```

I can update the value with the keys, but I don't know how to accept a value to the associated key in the object.

***Edit ** I found a relevant post from a while back...***
[How do you rerender a React component when an object's property is updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71320225/how-do-you-rerender-a-react-component-when-an-objects-property-is-updated)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this bit:

```
<textarea 
  value={answers[key]}
  onChange={
    (e) =>
      setAnswers(prevAnswer => ({
        ...prevAnswer,
        key: e.target.value
      }))
  } 
  type='text'
  required 
/>
```

is just going to set the literal key `"key"` to the new value. Instead we want to do this:

```
<textarea 
  value={answers[key]}
  onChange={
    (e) =>
      setAnswers(prevAnswer => ({
        ...prevAnswer,
        [key]: e.target.value // <-- note `[key]:` here rather than `key:`
      }))
  } 
  type='text'
  required 
/>
```